# SQL. Поиск по тексту одной ячейки совпадения с текстом из другой ячейки

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы Transactions и Users.

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать поиск в поле Transactions.Details по упоминанию значений в поле Users.UserId

Такое работает только при полном совпадении:

```
select * from Transactions where Details in (select distinct UserId from Users);
```

также как и

```
select * from Transactions where Details like (select distinct UserId from Users)
```

нужно частичное совпадение.
При попытке подставить знаки % 
`select * from Transactions where Details like %(select distinct UserId from Users)%` отображается ошибка

```
[14:07:02] Ошибка при выполнении SQL запроса к базе данных 'test_wallets': near "%": syntax error
```

Comment: Оператор `LIKE`?

Comment: нет, там тоже полное совпадение, добавление знаков % не катит, ругается на ошибку(

Comment: Правьте вопрос и добавляйте ошибку, на которую ругается.

Comment: Используйте синтаксис конкатенации строк явно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Знаки `%` должны быть строками, в зависимости от БД, это будет либо:

```
select * from Transactions where Details like (select distinct '%'||UserId||'%' from Users)
```

либо:

```
select * from Transactions where Details like (select distinct concat('%',UserId,'%') from Users)
```

Возможно еще потребуется приведение типа для `UserId`.